# CriteriaBuilder where clause with XMLType

Tags: oracle, jpa, oracle11g, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have a database column with XML. I am using `JPA` (eclipselink) to access it. The database is oracle so I am using `oracle.xdb.XMLType and a @Customizer` annotation. It all works great.

Now I need to use the `CriteriaBuilder` to create a query using the XML column in the where clause.

Basically I need to recreate this with `CriteriaBuilder` (I do have CriteriaBuilder working for non XML columns):

```
SELECT id, somecolumn, xmlcol FROM sometable WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(xmlcol,'//path/path')='somevalue';
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the JPA CriteriaBuilder function() API to call this function.

If you need to do something more advanced you could use an EclipseLink Expression query, or mix Expressions and Criteria,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#JpaCriteriaBuilder_and_EclipseLink_Extensions

Comment: Thank you, that got me on the right path. I just found this EclipseLink link which should be very helpful http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Expressions_(ELUG)#XMLType_Functions